# File & folder permission needed before installation of extension from Magento connect

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, downloader

I am trying to install an extension using magento connect but facing some issue.

[image]

Can anybody let me know what files &  folders permission we need to set before starting any magento extension installation from magento connect in magento 1.9.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Installing extension from magento connect your `downloader` folder should have write permission because magento stores extension there and after that process start for installing , so please give write permission to `downloader` folder you will get this folder in magento root

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 2):

This error is pop up because your downloader folder have not writable permission, Go to Magento home directory and just give permissions for your webroot.

```
chmod 777  -R downloader/*
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: any downside to granting it 777? instead of just read/write?

Answer (score 2):

If you get the error like above, please goto [Download extension](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) method.

Answer (score 1):

[It's not safe to use Magento connect for installing extension , click this link for more information.](https://www.integer-net.com/why-modules-shouldnt-be-installed-via-magento-connect-manager/)

in the worst case, if you want immediate solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. Let me know if you find any problems in this.

**Note** : As this is unofficial 3rd party site, there is no guarantee about security. but i tested many extensions, i did't faced any security problems....

Answer (score 0):

Upon trying all kinds of suggestions I narrowed this problem to one factor.
 Using a setup suggested for a Magento folder is most likely set to permissions **'0750'** or **'0755'**, but none of these would work for me.
 Setting the permissions to **'0775'** seem to allow the group to install the modules where needed.
[**-rwxrwxr-x** for those using Nautilus]

Setting the permissions to **'0775**' seem to allow the group to install the modules where needed. The second **7** gives group **'Write'** access.

Seems this is only slightly better than having the directories wide open at **'0777'** that would allow anyone access.
I have not tried **'0774'** (removes **'other'** Execute) or **'0755'** but this might getting Apache2 Group ownership to work without **'Write'** access.

On my system I have (running as Fcgi) SuExec at work for www-data and/or the same as the owner=group (owner:owner). [Virtualmin](https://www.virtualmin.com/)/[Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) is particular about this, and the Virtualmin LAMP-stack is not the same as my Ubuntu LAMP-stack (or generic Linux LAMP-stack).

So the easiest way so far is to change directory  to your Magento folder (directory) and the run:
`find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;`
for the entire folder and then redo folders **/media** and **/var** to
`find . -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;`.
Another way if you know your Perm's are set to **'0750'** could be;
`find . -type d ! -perm 0750 -exec chmod 775 {} \;`  
where the `-perm 0750` finds the existing permissions and `-exec chmod 775` changes them.

Magento connect does not seem to care is the files stay at **'0644'** so I did not do;
 `find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`, 
but if you have not already you might want to take this step. Mine are already that way!

Perhaps a script would be nice, but the various Directory structures change for OS to OS, so If I did one it would only be for my own?